# Is the static loading of shared libraries linked like dynamic loading or static linking?

Tags: linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

According to [this expert](http://www.quora.com/Systems-Programming/What-is-the-exact-difference-between-Dynamic-loading-and-dynamic-linking),

> **Dynamic loading** refers to mapping (or less often copying) an executable or library into a process's memory after is has started.  **Dynamic linking** refers to resolving symbols - associating their names with addresses or offsets - after compile time.

Hence, correspondingly: **static loading** refers to mapping an executable or libary into memory before it has started, and **static linking** refers to resolving symbols at compile time.

Now, when you do **static loading** and **static linking** of a library, the library's binary code is appended to your binary code, and the (function and variable) references your binary code makes to the library are *patched* (not sure if that's the correct term) so that they point to the correct positions.

This means that before static linking a call to a function

```
foo()
```

would give you (in x86 ASM), among others, an instruction like:

```
 call    0x00000000
```

and after static linking you have something like:

```
 call    0x00001043
```

where 0x00001043 is the entry point of the function foo in the binary code that is output by the linker.

Now, when you do **dynamic loading** and **dynamic linking**, you will call a library function by way of a function pointer:
    typedef int (*fun_ptr)(void);

```
library = dlopen("mylib.so");
fun_ptr foo = dlsym(library, "foo");
foo();
```

This mechanism is also how C++ virtual methods work. The address of the method to be called is resolved at runtime by making a function pointer to the method part of the instance (stored in the so-called vtable).

My question is this:

When you do **static loading** and **dynamic linking** of a shared library (for context, let's say a .so in linux), does this linking patch my binary's references like in the **static loading & linking** scenario, or does it work by way of function pointers like in the case of **dynamic loading & linking** and C++ virtual methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you do static loading and dynamic linking of a shared library

You don't do 'static loading' of a shared library.

Even though it looks to you as an end-user that e.g. `libc.so.6` is 'static loaded' at process startup, it is not in fact the case. Rather, the kernel 'static loads' the main binary and `ld-linux.so`, and then `ld-linux` *dynamic* loads all the other shared libraries.

> does this linking patch my binary's references like in the static loading & linking scenario, or does it work by way of function pointers like in the case of dynamic loading

It depends.

Usually shared libraries are linked from position-independent code (`PIC`), and work the way of function pointers (the pointers are stored in the `GOT` -- global offset table).

But sometimes shared libraries are linked from non-`PIC` code, and require "text relocations", which work similar to "static linking".

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful to know! Now I finally understand why I have to add the -fPIC flag when compiling shared libraries in my linux box :)

Some follow-up questions:

Do you know which systems use text relocations and which use global offset tables? Is it possible to compile a linux kernel to use text relocations instead of GOTs? Also, why are GOTs prefered? Faster loading is priviledged over faster runtime performance?

Comment: I found [this link](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/textrelocs.html) useful. It seems to imply that text relocations could not be performed by anything other than the kernel in a SELinux box (because memory pages can not be both writable and executable in SELinux).

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to produce an example of runtime static linking using libbfd (which is the library sitting beneath GNU binutils' ld linker): https://github.com/bloff/runtime-static-linking-with-libbfd